# How to implement DelayedJob custom job for Prawn PDF rendering?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job, prawn

Im trying to use DelayedJob to render Prawn PDFs.  Following the custom job code in the docs, I've come up with this:

```
 /lib/jobs/pdf_handling.rb

 RenderPdf = Struct.new( :id, :view_context ) do
   def perform
     user = User(id)
     pdf  = UserFolder.new( id, view_context )
     name = "user_folder_report.pdf"
     send_data pdf.render, filename: name, type: "application/pdf"
  end
end

PagesController.rb

def user_folder
  respond_to do |format|
    format.pdf do
      Delayed::Job.enqueue RenderPdf.new(@user, view_context)
    end
  end
end
```

this results in the error:

```
 uninitialized constant PagesController::RenderPdf
```

Adding required RenderPdf at the top of the PagesController doesn't help.

What am I missing?  How can I implement this so PDF generation occurs via DelayedJob?  Thanks.

## updates

When /jobs is moved under /apps the error changes to:

```
 can't dump anonymous module: #<Module:0x007fca7a3ae638>
```

/application.rb

```
 config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/assets/"]
```

## updates

I changed

```
  class RenderFolder < Struct.new( :type, :rating_id, :dis, :view_context )
    def perform
```

to

```
 class RenderFolder < ActiveJob::Base
   def perform(...)
```

Then, using ActiveJob, you can do

```
 RenderFolder.perform_later(...)
```

This seems to be working...Im still implementing.

Answer (score 1):

the `lib` folder is no longer loaded by default in rails. you can either add it to the `autoload_path` or (what i would do) just have it in some `app/xxx` folder. typically, i have `app/support` or something for arbitrary utility classes.

Comment: i originally had it in app/jobs. But got the same error. I'll move it out of lib and try again.